# Bulk Create Community Users

Tags: community

I have a requirement wherein I need to create about 3000+ Community Users.

Is there any automation available by which I can create those Community Users.

Answer (score 4):

I used the following instruction when I worked on the same task

[Official Salesfroce.com Knowledge Article: How do I import customer portal users?](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000004421&language=en_US)

First, you need to set up the Account or multiple Accounts for your Customer Portal or Partner portal Contacts. Then all the Contact records need to be created. Lastly you need to create the Portal Role that your Users will be using. If you are using multiple accounts then it will not be feasible to create all the roles in advance. THis process will still work but will default all roles to the standard user role for that account eg: Acme standard user.

Once this is set up, create a .csv file with the following information to create new users:

- ROLE ID (optional, otherwise default to user role)
- First Name
- LastName
- CONTACT ID (use the contact id of previously created contact)
- PROFILE ID
- Username
- Email
- Alias
- TimeZoneSidKey
- LocaleSidKey
- EmailEncodingKey
- LanguageLocaleKey

For some of the SID Key fields or any other questionable ones the user can use the Data Loader to export an existing user record to use as an example.
Once the file is completed upload with the Data Loader to the User's object.

Comment: Pavel, your answer becomes a lot more reliable if you at least include the relevant parts of the solution here in your answer. That way no one has to navigate away and there's no risk that the website you refer to is ever removed.

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke it's a link to official Salesforce.com Knowledge Article

Comment: I've seen knowledge articles dissapear. Thanks for the update.